# Open Chrome with Rails Feature Spec using Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't figure out how to make the feature specs work when running non-headless feature specs for Rails in Docker. I can get the Chrome to open, but I'm getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`  (basically, it's blank)

The whole source code is available at: https://github.com/amree/blog-example

Commands:

```
# chromedriver on the host
chromedriver --whitelisted-ips

# build the image
docker build -t blog_base --progress=plain --secret id=bundle_credentials,src=.env.development .

# run the test
docker compose run --rm web bundle exec rspec spec/features/user_creates_post_spec.rb
```

```rb
# spec/support/capybara.rb
require "capybara/rspec"
require "selenium-webdriver"

Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: false }

# Setup rspec
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    Capybara.server_host =  "0.0.0.0"
    Capybara.server_port = "31337"
    Capybara.app_host    = "http://127.0.0.1:31337"


    driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, options: {
      browser: :remote,
      # Couldn't use http://host.docker.internal:9515 for some reason, so, I just
      # use my current wifi IP here
      url: "http://192.168.1.244:9515",
      desired_capabilities: :chrome
    }
  end
end
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.3

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
  && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install rails:6.1.4.4 bundler:2.3.4
COPY Gemfile* /app
COPY bundle_install.sh .
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=bundle_credentials ./bundle_install.sh

RUN npm install -g yarn
COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN yarn install

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  chrome:
    image: blog_base
    command: bash -c "/usr/bin/true"
    ports:
      - "31337:31337"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    environment:
      - BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
      - RAILS_ENV=test
      - RACK_ENV=test
    depends_on:
      - db

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome

volumes:
  db: {}
  bundle: {}
  node_modules: {}
  redis: {}
```

The error:

```
2022-01-11 16:04:14 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] [:desired_capabilities] :desired_capabilities as a parameter for driver initialization is deprecated. Use :capabilities with an Array value of capabilities/options if necessary instead.
2022-01-11 16:04:14 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] [:browser_options] :options as a parameter for driver initialization is deprecated. Use :capabilities with an Array of value capabilities/options if necessary instead.
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 5.5.2 , codename: Zawgyi
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:31337
F

Failures:

  1) User creates post successfully
     Failure/Error: visit posts_path

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
         (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)

     [Screenshot Image]: /app/tmp/screenshots/failures_r_spec_example_groups_user_creates_post_successfully_168.png


     # 0   chromedriver                        0x000000010bcefe69 chromedriver + 5160553
     # 1   chromedriver                        0x000000010bc7a593 chromedriver + 4679059
     # 2   chromedriver                        0x000000010b82e2c8 chromedriver + 172744
     # 3   chromedriver                        0x000000010b8281b7 chromedriver + 147895
```

[image: error]

Comment: Is it possible for your to host relevant content (to reproduce above mentioned issue) in github or any public repository ?

Comment: According to me issue could be :  Capybara.app_host    = "http://127.0.0.1:43447"  - try replacing it with hostname or servicename of actual application.

Comment: @fly2matrix Shouldn't I be able to access it at `127.0.0.1`? What is the hostname and service name that you are suggesting? I didn't setup any DNS for this app. 

I've simplified the config and the repo can be accessed at https://github.com/amree/blog-example

Comment: @rprez Nop. Do reply here if you can figure it out lol

Answer (score 0):

When launching Chrome don't point it to the local address `127.0.0.1` because Docker starts the container up with its own IP (unless explicitly specified).

You have two options:

1. Run the app in a container and use the hostname

> Set the launch URL to the hostname of the Docker Container.
>
> The value would be `http://chrome:31337`, where `chrome` is the container name used in the Docker Compose file.

2. Allow the docker container to access the host ports. (If you are running the app outside of docker)

> To do this add the following line to the *selenium* container
>
> ```
> extra_hosts:
> - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
> ```
>
> Then set the value to `http://host.docker.internal:31337`.

Comment: I got `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` for the first option. I will try out the second option. Feel free to check the github repo if you want to.

Comment: I'm not sure why (2) is needed, care to explain further? I think the problem right now is that the chromedriver that launched chrome on the host can't access the capybara running in the chrome container.

I *think* it's ok to access it on 127.0.0.1 as the 31337 port has already been exposed?

Comment: If the application is running outside of docker (on the host) then the docker container (by default) can't access resources outside of Docker on the host. If you are running the application inside of docker, then you use a reference to the other docker-machine (that would be the docker-compose name, it's a dynamic DNS entry for the docker containers).